# runc container cpu usage

Tags: cpu-usage, linux-containers, runc

Where to look for `cpu usage` for a specific `runc` container? .
There is no file present in `/proc/<cid>/` (`<cid>` is the pid obtained from `runc list` command) by any cpu related name which gives cpu usage for that specific container.
In `/sys/fs/cgroup` there are files present under `cpu`, `cpuacct`, `cpu,cpuacct` directories. I don't see if there's any way to extract cpu usage form those files for a specific container.

Is there any way i can get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this, There are folders created by the name of the container which you are running under `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/user.slice/<container_folder>/cpuacct.usage`, `cpuacct.usage` gives information about the cpu time used by that container.

**Note:** Specifically talking about `runc` containers, don't know about others.